# Splitting Polygon based on overlaid vertices using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, splitting

Is there a way to split a polygon using overlaid vertices using ArcGIS Desktop?

I am trying to determine parcels that may be used for future development. I have both building and parcel shapefiles. The parcels I'd like to split based on the building vertices. An example is below:

[image]

From this, I'd like to split the parcel based on the building vertex with the maximum distance to the parcel boundary like so:

[image]

Comment: The furthest vertex from the parcel boundary is vertex no 4, i.e. western most

Comment: It's not clear to me how you are deciding the angle of that line used to split the polygon.